# What is $Ext^1 (M\otimes_R N,L)$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a ring, that $M$, $N$ and $L$ are right $R$-modules, and that $N$ is an $R-R$-bimodule.

Is there any formula for $Ext^1 (M\otimes_R N,L)$ or generally for $Ext^n (M\otimes_R N,L)?$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume $R$ is meant to be commutative; otherwise you need to be more precise about left/right modules.

Comment: It seems difficult to answer the question in this generality. You can get nice formulas if, for example, M or N is projective over R.

Comment: @YCor You are right. I consider $R$ is not commutative in general and all modules are right $R$-module.

Comment: @theL Could you give a formula for the question when $M$ or $N$ is projective?

Comment: If $M$ is an $(R_1,R_2)$-module and $N$ a $(R_2,R_3)$-module then $M\otimes_{R_2}N$ is a $(R_1,R_3)$-module. $M,N$ right $R$-modules is not enough to make sense of $M\otimes_R N$. (And you mean Ext as what?)

Comment: @YCor Yes. Naturally $N$ is an $R-R$-bimodule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from how the question is phrased that the OP is hoping for a kind of Hom-Tensor duality for Ext. The first comment below shows that in general

$$\operatorname{Ext}^n(M\otimes_R N,L) \not \cong \operatorname{Ext}^n(M,\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,L))$$

Instead, what you have are the well-known Ext-Tor relations. This makes sense: Ext is a left derived functor of Hom, so should play nicely with Tor, the right derived functor of $\otimes$.

In this answer, I'll show that Hom-Tensor duality of the sort that fails above for Ext holds for $\operatorname{Ext}_{dw}$, the subgroup of Ext for chain complexes consisting of short exact sequences that are degreewise split. This $\operatorname{Ext}_{dw}$ can be computed via the internal $\operatorname{Hom}$ in chain complexes. Let $S^n(M)$ be the chain complex with $M$ in degree $n$, 0 everywhere else, and all differentials 0. The Ext of chain complexes agrees with the Ext of modules, when they sit inside chain complexes via $S^0(-)$. Hence, $\operatorname{Ext}_{dw}(S^0(A),S^0(B))$ is also a subgroup of the usual $\operatorname{Ext}(A,B)$.
First, note that:
$$\operatorname{Ext}_{dw}^n(X,Y) \cong H_n \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y) \cong \operatorname{Ch}(R)(X,\Sigma^{-n}Y)/\sim, $$
where $\sim$ is chain homotopy equivalence, see Lemma 2.1 of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2004-356-08/S0002-9947-04-03416-6/S0002-9947-04-03416-6.pdf).

Let's apply this to your situation, letting $\otimes$ be the monoidal product in $\operatorname{Ch}(R)$: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Ext}_{dw}^n(S^0(M\otimes_R N),S^0(L)) &\cong H_n(\operatorname{Hom}(S^0(M\otimes_R N),S^0(L))) \\
&\cong H_n(\operatorname{Hom}(S^0(M)\otimes S^0(N),S^0(L))\\
&\cong H_n(\operatorname{Hom}(S^0(M),\operatorname{Hom}(S^0(N),S^0(L)))) \\
&\cong \operatorname{Ext}_{dw}^n(S^0(M),\operatorname{Hom}(S^0(N),S^0(L)))\\
&\cong \operatorname{Ext}_{dw}^n(S^0(M),S^0(\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,L)).
\end{aligned}
$$
Here I use that chain complex maps from $S^0(N)$ to $S^0(L)$ are the same as $R$-module maps from $N$ to $L$, since
$$\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)\cong \prod_i \operatorname{Hom}_R(X_i,Y_{n+i}),$$
and for $S^0(N)$ and $S^0(L)$ the only place this product doesn't vanish is $\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,L)$. We conclude that:

$$\operatorname{Ext}_{dw}^n(M\otimes_R N,L) \cong \operatorname{Ext}_{dw}^n(M,\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,L))$$

where modules sit inside chain complexes via the functor $S^0(-)$.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. If you let $(R,\pi)$ to be a dvr, $M=L=R$ and $N=R/\pi R$, $n=1$, then, the left side is $N$ and the right side is zero.

Comment: That's a good example, but I can't see anything wrong in the proof. Now I'm curious to see how this can be resolved.

Comment: When using Lemma 2.1, aren't you making the assumption that (i) Ext_{dw}^1(X,\Sigma^{-n-1}Y) = \Ext_{dw}^n(X,Y) (for whatever the latter means, since it is not defined in the cited paper)
(ii) That Ext_{dw}^n(M,N) = \Ext_R^n(M,N).

Comment: Indeed, Section 5 of the cited paper tells you that Ext^n_R(M,N) = Ch(R)(P_*,S^n(N))\~, where P_* is a projective resolution of M

Comment: Hi Drew. I was thinking of $Ext^1$ as the group of split short exact sequences, and $Ext_{dw}^1$ as the group of degreewise split short exact sequences of chain complexes. In this form, it seems to me that when the chain complexes have the form $S^0(-)$ then these groups agree. Am I wrong?

Comment: There should be more extensions in Ext^1 - it's equivalence classes of extensions of M by N. e.g., 0 --> Z/2 ---> Z/4 ---> Z/2 --> 0 corresponds to the non-zero element of Ext^1(Z/2,Z/2)

Comment: Ah, ok, that explains it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Is Ext^1 dw interesting for modules? If it’s supposed to be the subgroup of Ext^1 which consist of split sequences, isn’t that just zero? It seems like it is supposed to be capturing sequences of chain complexes which are split in each degree but not split as an ses of complexes, which can’t happen for things concentrated in one degree.

Comment: Well, the argument here about hom-tensor duality with $Ext_{dw}$ doesn't need things to be concentrated in one degree. I think you're right about $Ext_{dw}^1$ for modules, but are all the $Ext^n_{dw}$ boring?

Comment: @JamesCameron: $Ext^1_{dw}(X,Y)$ is the same as $K(R)(X,Y)$, i.e. Hom in the homotopy category of complexes, with chain homotopy equivalences sent to isomorphisms.